# Is it safe or reasonable for owl ontologies to be mutually (circularly) dependant?

Tags: ontology, owl, circular-dependency

Is it safe or reasonable for owl ontologies to be mutually (circularly) dependant? I ask this because of the potential I see for cross-domain data and reasoning. It seems to me that some of the technical limitations that might apply in mainstream executable programming languages don't necessarily have to apply here.

For example, I have two ontologies: 'Stuff' and 'Creature'. In 'Stuff' I define a PhysicalObject class, to denote that the inheritors have a position in space. In 'Creature' I define a Person class, denoting a member of society.

```xml
<!-- In 'Stuff' -->
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Stuff#PhysicalObject"/>

<!-- In 'Creature' -->
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Creature#Person"/>
```

As an individual Person instance occupies a position in space, it would seem appropriate to declare it a subClassOf PhysicalObject. This can be resolved by simply importing 'Stuff' in the 'Creature' ontology. However I also want to have a Property in 'Stuff' that refers to a Person in its range: isHeldBy.

```xml
<!-- In 'Creature' -->
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
  <owl:imports rdf:resource="Stuff" />
</owl:Ontology>
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Creature#Person"
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Stuff#PhysicalObject" />
</owl:Class>

<!-- In 'Stuff' -->
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
  <owl:imports rdf:resource="Creature" />
</owl:Ontology>
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="isHeldBy"> 
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="Stuff#PhysicalObject"/>
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="Creature#Person"/> 
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

Is this a safe thing to do? Is it a reasonable thing to expect? Is this supported by current implementations? Should we expect a graceful degrade of the ontologies axioms be available if either import is unavailable?

I realize there are hierarchical solutions to this, but I still feel this is a point worthy of discussion.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), or if you found another solution on your own, please post it as an answer and accept it so that others with the same question can find out what worked for you.

Comment: Your answer was quite helpful, though I feel it did not fully answer my questions.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't accept it, then. :)  Can you elaborate on what it doesn't address?  Perhaps we can investigate a bit more and get some more satisfactory answers.  (Let's aim for answers for all the questions tagged `owl` have answers!)

Comment: Really it was the flurry of questions underneath the second code block. It seems like you need both for either to function at all, and I was wondering if that was a geninue limitation.

Comment: The original question was if we could consider it safe or reasonable, and it sounds like the answer is not very safe though possibly reasonable.

Comment: Oh, I'd disagree on that, I guess. I think it might not be all that common, but it's certainly safe.  The definition of the imports closure is clear.  If you have ontologies A, B, and C, and A imports B, B imports C, and C imports A, then any ontology that imports any of them will include all the triples from all of them.  It's entirely safe;  you just might not encounter it very often in the wild (in the same way that you won't encounter lots of libraries that are mutually dependent on each other).

Comment: Ah, but yes, I see where this doesn't address the "what if one of them is missing" case.

Comment: Right. If one of them is missing, or has been modified (different version available). Like you said though, this probably won't come up in the wild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OWL 2 specification [section 3.4 Imports](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Imports) describes the semantics of imports, and does not prohibit circular imports. Rather, the semantics are defined in terms of the closure of the imports relationship.

Aesthetically, it might be desirable to refactor the common elements of *Stuff* and *Creature* into some upper ontology and have both *Stuff* and *Creature* import it, but that's not a technical requirement.  Otherwise, although you have two ontologies, it's almost as though you've only got one, since anything that imports one of them will necessarily import the other as well, and vice versa.